# Foreground service - Setting an indeterminate progress bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-progressbar, foreground-service

I'm creating a foreground service with an `indeterminate progress bar`.

```
public Notification createNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_TEST)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_download_complete)
                .setContentTitle("Test title")
                .setContentText("Test content")

                .setProgress(someInt, someInt, true)  //What do I set for these two params before the boolean flag
                

                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW) 
                .setAutoCancel(true);

       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = this.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_TEST,
                    "Test notification", 
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW 
            );
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }

        return builder.build();
    }
```

I'm trying to understand what values I have to set for the two int params in `.setProgress`. The last boolean flag in the method is for setting it as an determinate or indeterminate `progressbar`. So if it's a determinate, we can update the two ints to the percent we want `.setProgress(100, 10, true)`, but for indeterminate what should I set the values as?

[image]

I tried checking the method but it doesn't quite say what to use for indeterminate. Since passing null is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per documentation:](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification#progressbar)

> To display an indeterminate progress bar (a bar that does not indicate
> percentage complete), call setProgress(0, 0, true). The result is an
> indicator that has the same style as the progress bar above, except
> the progress bar is a continuous animation that does not indicate
> completion.

So, you need to set the two `int` values to 0